# How do I access network shares from Perl in Windows?

Tags: perl, windows-xp

How would you explore and write to windows shared directories in perl ?
Note: I don't have the right for network drive creation on the concerned workstation.
I tried (without results) the following :

```
my $ROOTDIR1 = 'c:/';
my $ROOTDIR2 = '//server/dir1/dir2/';
sub dtest {
  my $ROOTDIR = shift;
  warn "Testing '$ROOTDIR'.";
  opendir( SHAREFILE, "$ROOTDIR" ) or warn "1 -> " . $!;
  my @files = <$ROOTDIR*>;
  warn ("2 -> nothing !") if (!scalar @files);
  chdir $ROOTDIR or warn "3 -> " . $!;
}
dtest($ROOTDIR1);
dtest($ROOTDIR2);
```

But as shown by the following output :

```
Testing 'c:/'. at E:\test\a.pl line 5.
Testing '//server/dir1/dir2/'. at E:\test\a.pl line 5.
1 -> No such file or directory at E:\test\a.pl line 6.
2 -> nothing ! at E:\test\a.pl line 8.
3 -> No such file or directory at E:\test\a.pl line 9.
```

None of those methods are working.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UNC paths work for me, in ActivePerl 5.12.1 and Cygwin Perl 5.10.1, without a hitch. I would first of all guess that there is no path `'//server/dir1/dir2'` and I can only think that what you're passing is not a legitimate UNC path to wherever you're actually trying to get.

- Barring that, is it timing out, perhaps? I know that if you do not have a drive mapped to a particular share in Windows, it can be a bear trying to bring up a network share with a bare UNC path, it can often take minutes to load in Explorer.
- Another thing to check is perhaps this is a share that would require you to enter a password upon connecting. I'm not sure if Perl covers the signing on process in Windows. Maybe your network shares only respond to programs who know how to answer a challenge given to them by the server.

Comment: As you said, my path isn't a legitimate UNC path : There was a right assignation issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The UNC path is case sensitive - caught me out

Answer (score 0):

<s>UNC paths should have backslashes.</s>

Comment: At least on Activestate perl, that's not the case. It maps the forwards slashes to backslashes for you so that Unix folk like me don't have to retrain our brains.

Comment: Okay, I had the suspicion that only worked for traditional file paths, but could not try it out for a lack of Windows. Thanks for confirming.